# Users that dont contain; filter and list if more than one... MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table;

```
User         app
1stLineS     Citrix Delivery Services Console
1stLineS     Mencap@Work2-1
1stLineS     PB Service Desktop
1stlineWB    PB Service Desktop
aabidam  Business Object Full Client
aabidam  Epicor
aabidam  Mencap Desktop with Acrobat
aabidam  Powerplan
aabidam  Therefore Navigator
aabidam  Thin Client Desktop
aarong   Mencap @ Work Desktop
AarthiT  Mencap@Work2-1
AbbeyY   Mencap@Work2-1
abbiemc  Mencap@Work2-1
abbyf    Mencap@Work2-1
abbygailf    Mencap@Work2-1
Abbyh    GLH Contractors Web Portal
abdio    
abdio    PB Service Desktop
abdio    RDP NC-BACKUP01
abdouD   Mencap@Work2-1
abdulm   Mencap@Work2-1
AbigailE     Mencap@Work2-1
AbigailJ     Mencap Desktop with Acrobat
AbigailJ     Mencap@Work2-1
abim     Mencap@Work2-1
abiodunb     Mencap@Work2-1
abiodunb     Powerplan
adamd    ActiveH
adamd    Mencap@Work2-1
AdamHal  Mencap@Work2-1
adamhe   Mencap Desktop with Acrobat
adamhe   Mencap@Work2-1
adamhe   Powerplan
AdamK    Mencap@Work2-1
AdamL    Epicor
AdamL    Mencap@Work2-1
AdamL    Powerplan
AdamL    Saturn Live
AdamL    Therefore Navigator
AdamL    Therefore Viewer
adamr    ActiveH
adamr    ALMSdotNET
adamr    Epicor
adamr    FirstClass
adamr    Mencap@Work2-1
adamr    Peterborough Desktop
adamr    Peterborough Desktop with Acrobat
adamr    Saturn Live
adamr    Saturn MS ACCESS ADD-ONS
adamr    Therefore Navigator
adamr    Therefore Viewer
AdamTh   Mencap Desktop with Office 2010
AdamTh   Mencap@Work2-1
AdamTh   Microsoft Excel
AdamTh   OfficeBase Live
AdamTh   Peterborough Desktop with Acrobat
AdamTh   ResourceLink-Aurora
AdamTh   Thin Client Desktop
Adelec   Mencap Desktop with Office 2010
AdeleC   Mencap@Work2-1
AdeolaA  Mencap@Work2-1
adetolaok    Mencap@Work2-1
```

I need to get back

aabidam

because is the only user with more than one app and it doesn't have "Mencap@work2-1"

Im using;

```
WHERE publishedapp LIKE \"%Mencap@Work2-1%\"
OR publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%@%\"
AND publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
AND publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%RDP%\"
```

to filter desktops but I dont think this is the right way to procedd as I want.

eventually Id like to do something like

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT publishedapp SEPARATOR \"<br>\") AS publishedapp
```

to list the apps

I supose I have to user HAVING, COUNT and SUM in some way but I havent been able to crack it.

I do the oposite, that is select users that have a "Mencap@Work2-1" and at least an app with this

```
SELECT DISTINCT username,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT publishedapp SEPARATOR \"<br>\") AS publishedapp
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp LIKE \"%Mencap@Work2-1%\"
OR publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%@%\"
AND publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
AND publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%RDP%\"
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT publishedapp) > 1 AND
SUM(DISTINCT publishedapp LIKE \"%Mencap@Work2-1%\") > 0
```

Comment: What about `abdio`, who has 3 and none of them is Mencap@Work2-1?

Comment: you're right that user should go too.

Comment: I suppose wouldnt come on my list becuase non of the "apps" he's using are apps but desktops, it need to be and app... :s

Comment: So you want to exclude users who have any of `publishedapp LIKE '%Mencap@Work2-1%', publishedapp LIKE '%Desktop%',  publishedapp LIKE '%RDP%'` ?

Comment: no, only the ones that have mencap@work2-1 but the rest must have at least and app that is not one of '%Desktop%', '%RDP%' ...

Comment: what exactly is your question? it is a little bit confusing

Comment: Very confusing...
If user doesnt have any apps Mencap@Work2-1 and at least one app that doesnt contain 'Desktop' or 'RDP' or '@' then list user...
Hope that makes more sense @inetphantom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, no users that have 'Mencap@Work2-1' app.
The others, as long they have more that two apps that are not 'Desktop', 'RDP', '@'

Get all users that have one of the unwanted apps and remove them from the total set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM tbl_name
WHERE username NOT IN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT username FROM tbl_name WHERE  publishedapp  LIKE "%Mencap@Work2-1%" )
AND publishedapp NOT LIKE "%@%" AND publishedapp NOT LIKE "%Desktop%" AND publishedapp NOT LIKE "%RDP%"
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: the only "app" they cant have is 'Mencap@Work2-1' the rest doesnt matter as long as there is more than two apps that dont contain 'Desktop', 'RDP' or '@'...
`If not  'Mencap@Work2-1' then If not  'Desktop' or 'RDP' or '@' then is an app`, if one user has more than two of this `and user has 0 'Mencap@Work2-1'` then list user...
is the best way I can explain it

Comment: el puto amo! @jaimetotal It was so simple... tx!